# function that takes a tmux session and restarts it

Tags: python, unix, process, tmux

I want to write a customize program in libtmux, that takes input of session name, stop that session and restart it.

```
def new_function():

    import libtmux
    server = libtmux.Server()
    print server.list_sessions()
    session= input('Enter Session Name:')
    print (session)
    my_session = server.find_where({"session_name": session})

    server.attach_session(target_session=my_session)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print '............'

    new_function()
```

It prints the sessions in tmux and takes a input but crash right after it. After entering the session name , I want it to stop that session and restarts it.

Answer (score 1):

See next sourcecode in `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/libtmux/server.py`, the para target_session should be a `string`, the name of the session.

In your place, it is `session`, not `my_session`, `my_session`'s type is `libtmux.session.Session` not `string`, so `server.attach_session(target_session=my_session)` crash.

```
def attach_session(self, target_session=None):
    """``$ tmux attach-session`` aka alias: ``$ tmux attach``.

    :param: target_session: str. name of the session. fnmatch(3) works.
    :raises: :exc:`exc.BadSessionName`
    """
```

In fact, you did not need this function, you just need to use `kill_session` & `new_session` to make your aims.